# Matlab .wav normalization

Tags: matlab, audio, import, wav, normalize

I'm currently working in a project where I record sound using sound meter and then export the resulting files in `.wav` format.

After that, I import the `.wav` files into `MATLAB` using `audioread` function. I realized that the data is normalized between -1 and 1 (default option). This means that each different file is normalized using their respective extreme values ?
If that is true how can I get non-normalized data from `.wav` file, so I can compare the spectrum of two different files in terms of amplitude?
What I need is exactly a file having amplitude (in dB,volts,whatever...) as function of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare two files that have different bit-depths then the best thing to do is to allow matlab to normalize the audio.

A 0 dBFS sine wave will have a max peak of 32767 in 16-bit signed and a 127 in 8-bit signed, for example. With the normalization they will both be converted to +1.0 (1.0 = 0 dBFS).  Without normalization just think about what the two signals would look like in the time domain. The 8-bit signal would tiny in comparison to the 16-bit. In fact, it would be 8-bits or 48dB down!

Comment: ok i think i understand. thanks! but to end all doubts: i'm comparing two different recordings but they are recorded with the same resolution (16 bits) . I can import them to Matlab with audioread , and despite that, their amplitudes are comparable?

Comment: Yes, the amplitudes are comparable. Both files are scaled in exactly the same manner.

Comment: @jaket, is there a convention so that you can do the same comparison regardless of where the normalization was done? Eg, 2 different WAV files that are imported?

Comment: @Vass I don't know if there is a convention but I can tell you the way I've always done it. I load the samples from a file into a 32-bit integer with the data left justified and then convert to float.  e.g. `int intSample = shortSample << 16`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is **YES**, the data is being normalized by the `audioread` function. 
When using the `audioread` function you should specify the output data type. There are two options for the data type:

1. **double**: Double-precision **normalized** samples (**default**).
2. **native**: Samples in the native data type found in the file.

The default option, which you are using, is the first one that gives you normalized samples. As you can see, if the `dataType` is `native`, then the output can be one of several `MATLAB` data types as shown in the following table, depending on the file format and the `BitsPerSample` value of the input file.

[image]

Thus you need to change the data type to get different result. You can try the following form of function usage:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread(filename,'native');
```

In addition you can call `audioinfo` to determine the `BitsPerSample` value of the file.

The other option which is more suitable for `.wav` audio format, is using [wavread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html) function again with specified data type. However, it is going to be removed from `MATLAB` in the future.

Comment: Thnx for the answer!  Isn't the difference just in the interval of normalization?? I mean, if two files are normalized with different reference values I can't compare their amplitudes either with [-1 1] or with [-32767 32768] intervals.

Comment: @pragal it won't be normalized if you use native option.

Comment: @NKN, are the files normalized in the WAV file or at the time of the reading/import process?